# Reinstalling windows 7 on an SSD drive

Tags: windows, ssd, setup

I installed Windows 7 on a new OCZ Vertext 2 SSD drive. A few days later I decided to reinstall Windows 7 again. So I went through the normal installation process, deleted the partitons with the setup program, formated the drive and so on, completed the installation. I rebooted and everything looked okay. I installed some drivers and rebooted again. This time the "old" istallation of Windows appeared with installed programs, desktop backround and all. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is the old drive still attached?  Is it booting off the old drive not the new one? PS: Love my SSD with Win 7.  Huge performance boost.

Comment: My thoughts are along the same lines as geoffc's, do you even have more than one drive? i wonder if it did get installed to a different drive the second time.

Comment: No the SSD drive is the only one, the machine is a laptop Dell Latitude E6510.